# why this code throws exception?

Tags: java

I have a void method which is part of a flow run by quartz scheduler task.

The content of this method is this code:

```
try {
        InputStream ris = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("arialuni.ttf");
        byte[] ttfAfm = new byte[1];
        if (ris != null) {
            System.out.println("toByteArray START");
            ttfAfm = IOUtils.toByteArray(ris);
            System.out.println("toByteArray END");
        } else
            System.out.println("input stream from arailuni.ttf is null!!!");
        ris.close();
        ris = null;
        bfChinese =
                BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, ttfAfm, null);
        System.out.println("in myinit() try catch END");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception encountered at myinit() " + e);
    }
```

It's very strange that **this works nice about 30 times** (basically, the scheduler scans a directory, take any PCL found and converts it to PDF using this arialuni.ttf font) but suddenly it gives the follwing exception:

```
19:06:24,316 INFO  [STDOUT] toByteArray START
19:06:28,218 ERROR [ReportPollingJob] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptio
n
//nothing else here (yes, the exception is only one line...)
```

at `IOUtils.toByteArray(ris)`

Can it be because of memory?
It's very strange that it does not go to my catch but just throws this exception...

Can you give a hint?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to mdma: I've changed to catch(Throwable e) and now I see:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemory: JavaHeap Space
```

which will not be easy to solve...

Comment: Any more info on the exception, as to what its actually complaining of?

Comment: This is basically the main problem, that I do not have any other output after this short error....

Comment: Normally java is incredibly vocal on its exceptions. Often to the point you wish it wasnt.

Comment: Use a debugger and see what's really happening.

Comment: change your catch(Exception e) to catch(Throwable e) so that you really do catch all exceptions. You'll then at least see in system.out what the real exception is.

Comment: Change to:  System.out.println("expection encountered at myinit()"); e.printStackTrace();  By converting the Exception to a String, you're losing the stack trace; this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: System.out.println("exception encountered at myinit() " + e); will not print out the stack trace, use e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InvocationTargetException` is just a wrapper for the real exception, so you should analyze that (via `getCause()`). It is probably an `OutOfMemoryError`, which does not subclass `Exception`. To catch every error condition, catch `Throwable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not relevant to the error you are seeing, but it is an error:

If ris is null, you will get a NullPointerException. You have to exit the method after

```
System.out.println("input stream from arailuni.ttf is null!!!");
```

or it wil next try to execute

```
ris.close()
```

resulting in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    InputStream ris = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("arialuni.ttf");
    byte[] ttfAfm = new byte[1];
    if (ris != null) {
        System.out.println("toByteArray START");
        ttfAfm = IOUtils.toByteArray(ris);
        System.out.println("toByteArray END");
    } else
        System.out.println("input stream from arailuni.ttf is null!!!");
    ris.close(); // it will through NullPointerException in ris is null
    ris = null;
    bfChinese =
    BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, ttfAfm, null);
    System.out.println("in myinit() try catch END");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception encountered at myinit() " + e);
}
```

When working with resource the good practice is like as below

```
InputStream resource;
try {
    resource = createResource();
    //use resource object whatever way you want
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if(resource != null) {
        resource.close();
    }
}
```

Above procedure is true for any kind of resource.